# Increase year after every 3 iterations while looping

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, php-carbon

I have an array contain `n` number of elements can be 6 or 8, like that:

```
$langs = ["PHP", "JAVA", "Ruby", "C", "C++", "Perl"];
```

I would like to add one year evenly next to the elements

**Desired output in case of 6 elements:**

- PHP - 2022
- JAVA - 2022
- Ruby - 2022
- C - 2023
- C++ - 2023
- Perl - 2023

**Desired output in case of 9 elements:**

- PHP - 2022
- JAVA - 2022
- Ruby - 2022
- C - 2023
- C++ - 2023
- Perl - 2023
- Python - 2024
- Javascript - 2024
- Mysql - 2024

My try :

```
$date = Carbon::now();
foreach($langs as $key => $lang){
   if(count($langs) % $key == 0){
       echo $lang .' - '. $date->addYear(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bump the year every time `$key` is not zero and `$key / 3` has no remainder.

Code: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/c57fede9399c5b36e2d023c6beefb70e/))

```
$langs = ["PHP", "JAVA", "Ruby", "C", "C++", "Perl", "Perl", "Python", "Javascript", "Mysql"];
$date = Carbon::now();
foreach ($langs as $key => $lang){
   if ($key && $key % 3 === 0) {
       $date->addYear();
   }
   echo $lang .' - '. $date->year . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

---

To be perfectly honest, I don't see any benefit is calling a datetime wrapper for this very basic task. You can easily replace all usage of Carbon with PHP's native `date()` function. ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/961332d5d396f6bc1ff1a8ae3d3527db/))

```
$langs = ["PHP", "JAVA", "Ruby", "C", "C++", "Perl", "Perl", "Python", "Javascript", "Mysql"];
$year = date('Y');
foreach ($langs as $key => $lang){
   if ($key && $key % 3 === 0) {
       ++$year;
   }
   echo $lang .' - '. $year . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `%3` as suggested by @mickmackusa but I would avoid incrementing the year of a date object as here you just need to get the year number and increment it (the month/day/hour/etc. is not an info you need to keep):

```
$langs = ["PHP", "JAVA", "Ruby", "C", "C++", "Perl", 'foo', 'bar', 'bam'];
$year = Carbon::now()->year;

foreach ($langs as $key => $lang){
   if ($key && $key % 3 === 0) {
       $year++;
   }
   echo $lang .' - '. $year . PHP_EOL; 
}
```